# How to trigger a function from a object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get the console.log  to output  `true` or `false` on click of `.icons` div.

Here is some live code: [codepen](http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/IahFy?editors=101)

I have a model called `navigation`

```
$scope.navigation = {
  status: false;

}
```

And a big object that will toggle the ui

```
$scope.toggle = {
  menu: function() {
    $scope.navigation.status = !$scope.navigation.status;
    alert($scope.navigation.status);
  }

};
```

The trigger is an `ng-click="open.menu()"` :

```
<div class="icons " ng-repeat="(key, val) in squares" ng-style="perspective" ng-click="toggle.menu()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
toggle.menu()
```

instead of

```
open.menu()
```

Comment: Ahh i found out it was the perspective that made it wonky if you look at codepen you'll see